# Changing the application file of interest for uwsgi?

Tags: python, flask, configuration-files, uwsgi

I am setting up a webservice using uWSGI for Python. As a part of that I have created `uwsgi.ini`, with the following contents:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file=app.py
```

This works: it executes the Flask application `app.py`, located at `src/app.py`. However, I now want the webservice to look one folder further, to `src/signpostlab/app.py`. However, the following:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file=../signpostlab/app.py
```

Did not work. Indeed, [the page](https://tools.wmflabs.org/signpostlab/) still seems to point at the old file!

Am I filling this information out incorrectly? Is there a way to change this behavior?

Edit: `uwsgi.log` says:

```
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /data/project/signpostlab/www/python/venv
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads$
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x9ae860
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 363960 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
failed to open python file app.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
mounting /data/project/signpostlab/www/python/src/app.py on /signpostlab
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='/signpostlab') ready in 17 seconds on interpreter 0x9ae$
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 12292)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 12300, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 12301, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 12302, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 12303, cores: 1)
[pid: 12303|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.68.21.81 () {34 vars in 574 bytes} [Mon Oct 19 $
[pid: 12302|app: 0|req: 1/2] 10.68.21.81 () {32 vars in 543 bytes} [Mon Oct 19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project's base path should be an absolute path in the config file. I guess your project's directory looks something like this:

```
$ tree -L 1 /data/project/signpostlab
├── app.py
├── uwsgi.ini
└── venv
```

In this case you can use the following `uwsgi.ini` config file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir     = /data/project/signpostlab
wsgi-file = app.py
venv      = venv
http      = :9090
```

It will chdir into the project's dir, where the app.py and the virtualenv's directory exist. The http line means that the app will be at localhost:9090